# Is there any way to add non-reuseable Blocks or Design Patterns in WordPress Gutenberg Editor?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I have an issue with the Gutenberg blocks in WordPress. I save a section of text with an image as a reusable block. However, if I insert that block multiple times on the page and change one image, all of the images are changing.

I can't seem to find any workaround for this. I want to be able to change each image individually. I even tried using "Design Patterns" however the results are the same.

Is there any solution to this?

Comment: Did you convert the reusable blocks to regular blocks after inserting them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to convert the reusable block to regular blocks before you can update the images individually. There is a button in the toolbar when you select the block that allows you to do this:

[image: Convert reusable block to regular blocks]